# JQuery UI: Sortable element underlying the absolute DIV draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have code:

```
<div class="content">
    <div id="sortable">
        <div class="guide">Element 1</div>
        <div class="guide">Element 2</div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="overlay" style="position: absolute; display:block;">
</div>
```

I have the script:

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
    revert: true
});

$( ".guide" ).live({
    mouseover: function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();

        var item = $(this);

        var width = item.outerWidth();
        var height = item.outerHeight();

        var posTop = item.position().top + ((item.outerHeight(true) - item.outerHeight()) / 2);
        var posLeft = item.position().left + ((item.outerWidth(true) - item.outerWidth()) / 2);


        $('.overlay').css({left: posLeft, top: posTop, width: width, height: height});
    }
});
```

That is, I have a sortable DIV, but an absolute DIV that overrides your items with mouseover event. But I can no longer sort underlying elements.

For technical reasons I need to have this on DIV elements. I made an example on jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/roneioliveira/NPdnv/4/

Comment: what happens if you remove the event.preventDefault(); ?

Comment: The preventDefault () has nothing to do with the problem at hand. Thank you.